# Is there a way to get imageZMQ working on android using Kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, pyzmq

I am running a client on android using Kivy that sends camera frames to a server PC. The entire code for both server and client runs fine when testing both scripts locally on the computer. The problem comes when using the buildozer to build the app for android.

After building the Kivy app to android with the buildozer successfully, the app crashes when it runs on the phone.

The traceback shows the following error when running on android:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq'`

*side-note: android perms are requested before debugging.*

This error only appears when testing on android, even when the buildozer includes `zmq` and `imagezmq` in the `buildozer.spec` file.

To me it appears that the buildozer fails to grab the dependencies for `imagezmq` when trying to create an apk.

Below is the code I used for client, server and the `buildozer.spec` file.

(Kivy Client; works on PC, but not on android.)
main.py

```py
import time
# MUST >> import the android permission before building
# from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
# request_permissions([
#             Permission.CAMERA,
#             Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
#             Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
#             Permission.INTERNET,
#             Permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
#         ])
time.sleep(1)
from kivy import *
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import imagezmq
import cv2
import numpy as np

server_ip = '10.42.0.1' #PC server local IP
port = 5555

sender = imagezmq.ImageSender(connect_to=f"tcp://{server_ip}:{port}")
class TestCamera(App):    
    
    def sendFrame(self, *args):
        height, width = self.cam.texture.height, self.cam.texture.width

        #get kivy image in form of numpy ndarray.
        frame = np.frombuffer(self.cam.texture.pixels, 'uint8')
        frame = frame.reshape(height, width, 4)      
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)
        
        #Frame Res
        #webcam is 640*360
        fw,fh = 640,360
        frame= cv2.resize(frame,(fw,fh),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
         
        #SEND TO SERVER HERE
        sender.send_image(server_ip, frame)

        #Display Image on Screen
        buffer = cv2.flip(frame,-1).tostring()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(fw, fh), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer,colorfmt='bgr',bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture
        
        Clock.schedule_once(self.sendFrame, 1.0/60.0)

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation= 'vertical')
        #webcam is 640*480
        self.cam = Camera(index=-1,play = True)
        self.image = Image( allow_stretch=True)
        layout.add_widget(self.image)        
        return layout
    
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.sendFrame, 5)
        

app = TestCamera()
app.run()
```

(PC Server) Server.py

```py
# This code is for the server 
# import the libraries
import socket, cv2, pickle,struct,time
from imutils import build_montages
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import imagezmq

# initialize the ImageHub object
imageHub = imagezmq.ImageHub()

ip = '10.42.0.1' #Host IP
port = 5555

lastActive = {}
lastActiveCheck = datetime.now()
ESTIMATED_NUM_PIS = 1
ACTIVE_CHECK_PERIOD = 10
ACTIVE_CHECK_SECONDS = ESTIMATED_NUM_PIS * ACTIVE_CHECK_PERIOD

print("LISTENING AT:",ip)

while True:
    # receive host name and frame from phone and acknowledge
    # the receipt
    (host_ip, frame) = imageHub.recv_image()
    imageHub.send_reply(b'OK')

    # if a device is not in the last active dictionary then it means
    # that its a newly connected device
    if host_ip not in lastActive.keys():
        print("[INFO] receiving data from {}...".format(host_ip))

    # record the last active time for the device from which we just
    # received a frame
    lastActive[host_ip] = datetime.now()

    #Show frames on a window
    cv2.imshow('Received Frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == '13':
        break
```

The `buildozer.spec` file used to build to android is configured as follows.

```
[app]


# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 26

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 24

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 19c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
android.ndk_api = 24



[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to awkwardly answer the question I posted by providing the solution that worked for me.

`pyzmq` must be added before `zmq` and `imagezmq` in the requirements inside the `buildozer.spec` file.

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,numpy,pyzmq,zmq,opencv==4.5.4,imagezmq==1.1.1
```

The app runs on android now.