# Imagezmq on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I've built an application with Kivy that uses Imagezmq to send opencv frames from client to server.
it works very well on PC, but I want it on Android device, I tried to build it with buildozer and it was built sucessfuly, but when launching the app on Android device it crashes and when checking adb logcat, it says:
/arm64-v8a/imagezmq/imagezmq.py", line 12, in 
07-04 15:03:34.303 19342 19379 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq'
07-04 15:03:34.303 19342 19379 I python  : Python for android ended.

buildozer.spec

```
requirements = python3,kivy,opencv,numpy,imagezmq

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.

#android.api = 31



# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.

#android.minapi = 21



# (int) Android SDK version to use

#android.sdk = 20



# (str) Android NDK version to use

#android.ndk = 23b



# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.

#android.ndk_api = 21
```

I followed [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788245/is-there-a-way-to-get-imagezmq-working-on-android-using-kivy), the build did not sucessed, as it failed trying to download libzmq:

```
Making all in doc

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/test/Desktop/opencamera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libzmq/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libzmq/doc'

make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/Desktop/opencamera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libzmq/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libzmq/doc'

make[1]: Entering directory '/home/test/Desktop/opencamera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libzmq/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libzmq'

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-mtrie.lo

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-polling_util.lo

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-pollset.lo

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-proxy.lo

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-precompiled.lo

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-pub.lo

  CXX      src/src_libzmq_la-pull.lo

In file included from src/mtrie.cpp:32:

./src/generic_mtrie_impl.hpp:52:46: error: ISO C++ requires the name after '::~' to be found in the same scope as the name before '::~' [-Werror,-Wdtor-name]

template <typename T> zmq::generic_mtrie_t<T>::~generic_mtrie_t ()

                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~

                                             ::generic_mtrie_t

1 error generated.

make[1]: *** [Makefile:4468: src/src_libzmq_la-mtrie.lo] Error 1

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/Desktop/opencamera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libzmq/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libzmq'

make: *** [Makefile:6680: all-recursive] Error 1





  STDERR:



# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=camstream', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,libzmq,kivy,pyzmq,opencv,numpy,imagezmq', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/test/Desktop/opencamera/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
```

I also tried removing imagezmq from code, the app worked on Android, but I have to use imagezmq to send frames, is there any other module I can use in Kivy that works on Android to do same job that imagezmq does?